# Paste HTML between <code><pre></pre></code> in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am developing HTML lessons for a youth summer camp and I would like to copy HTML snippets from source view then paste them in design view between `<code><pre></pre></code>` and have Visual Studio 2013 automatically replace `<` `>` with `&lt;` `&gt;` accordingly.

I researched and found the article [Paste Operations in the HTML Designer of Visual Web Developer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05xf99c0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and it indicates there is an additional option in the edit menu called **paste alternative** but as you can see in this screenshot, there is no such option. Is it possible to change a setting or something to add such an option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your Visual Studio specific feature but Try this:
http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Answer (score 0):

Will "Copy as HTML" vs2013 extension will help you?

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf